# Please identify this ceiling texture

Tags: ceiling, texture

[image]

Please identify this ceiling texture

Thank you!

Comment: Which stipple brush will match my pattern?

Comment: Is this in a manufactured home?

Answer (score 1):

OK, i can identify it.

It is That ugly texture for the 70's that the neighbor lady talked my mom into letter her put on my bedroom ceiling.

She also did one on the living room ceiling that was like a swirl, she would dip a brush in mud, stick it on the ceiling (*poke the ceiling*)  and turn it before pulling straight away from the ceiling.

I think she had stock in the mud company because it uses a lot of mud.

I also had red white and blue shag carpet in 1976. *And you wonder where i get my warped sense of humor.*

> Which stipple brush will match my pattern?

One possibility is they used a straight brush, loaded it with mud and poked the ceiling, pulled straight back and then turned the brush and poke and turned the brush and poked and tur- - - ked.

Answer (score 0):

That is a stippled ceiling.

[Supporting link](https://www.google.com/search?q=stippled%20ceiling&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS749US750&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBmoT19eLcAhVkRN8KHTAkBegQ_AUICygC&biw=1728&bih=788)

Comment: Could be a round supple brush or sponge matching textures is one of the hardest things to do in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of a plastic bag texture - where the plaster is spread on smooth-ish, then a sponge or cloth is put inside a clean plastic bag, lightly touched to the wet plaster, and then pulled straight down.

I'd suggest doing a practice run on a scrap board, both to confirm the right technique and to get your hand in.

Or don't - stippling is no longer trendy.  For a modern look, scrape it all off with a hoe, sand flat and prime/paint.  This is a super messy task.